# Am I able to pin files to the launcher?

Tags: unity, 11.10, launcher, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a document shortcut to the Unity Panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89576/how-do-i-add-a-document-shortcut-to-the-unity-panel)

I am working on a project, and I'd like to be able to pin it to the launcher (as opposed to pinning the app to open it).  So, if possible, show me how, and if not, well, you know what to do.  Help is appreciated.

PS: I'm using 11.10

Answer (score 0):

If the project is one document, don't is posible pin this document from the launcher.If the project is on other form, answer and i help you