# How do I add a document shortcut to the Unity Panel?

Tags: unity, launcher, scripts, shortcuts, document

In Gnome 2, I used to be able to drag a particular document, for example, my_to_do_list.txt to the panel. It was quick access to my daily to do list, which opened up in Gedit.

This is the same case for when I want to add bash scripts to the unity launcher, but they opened up either in a terminal or simply loaded.

Now things seem a little harder with adding document short cuts to the unity panel launcher.

I've seen howtos for this, however, when I right click on my desktop, there is no option to create launcher. Only to create a new folder, or a new empty file.

Are there any really quick ways to make document shortcuts in the unity launcher?

Will Ubuntu be bringing in a simpler method to make document short cuts?

Comment: This site works best with singular questions - try not to ask multiple questions.  Some of these have already been answered - just do a quick search.  Please re-edit your question to ask just one.

Answer (score 2):

You can **manually add your favourite files in the Quicklist** of a Launcher-icon so that it looks like in this screenshot for LibreOffice Writer:

[image]

I describe the way for Precise Pangolin using **Ubuntu Tweak** (Version 0.7.0) - using **MyUnity** is similar:

Open **Ubuntu Tweak** > **QuickLists Editor** > click on **LibreOffice-Writer** on the left side > click on the little **Plus**-symbol > Enter the **Name** of the file (it's the name that will be shown in the Quicklist) > In the **Command**-field enter: `libreoffice --writer /Path/to/file/MyFavouriteText.odt` (e.g. `libreoffice --writer ~/Documents/MyFavouriteText.odt` or `libreoffice --writer "~/Documents/My Favourite Text.odt"`) > Press **Save**. Repeat this procedure to add further odt-files to the quicklist.

Note: I had to **login again** to make the behaviour of starting a favourite file from the Quicklist work properly.

Concerning **LibreOffice Calc** the command would be:

```
libreoffice --calc /Path/to/file/MyFavouriteSpreadsheet.ods
```

Concerning **Gedit** the command would be:

```
gedit /Path/to/file/MyFavouriteNote.txt
```

This solution also works when - for privacy reasons - someone has Zeitgeist totally disabled or just textfiles and/or spreadsheets excluded from activity-logging. Without Zeitgeist enabled, the Dash will show no Recently Used Files.

Answer (score 1):

Unity runs on both Gnome 2 and Gnome 3. The panel you are referring to, is called Gnome Panel and is the shell we've used in Ubuntu in all versions prior to 11.04.

The Unity Launcher is not designed for bookmarks, but for applications. To get quick access to files and folders, use the files and folders lens. The quickest way to access it is by using the super (winkey)+F keyboard shortcut. Folders that you have bookmarked in Nautilus will be displayed in that list. You'll also get the most recent/frequent documents.

It's very easy to add another panel, though. You can add a Gnome Panel, for instance, if you're comfortable with them. Just install the [gnome-panel](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-panel) package, press alt+f2 and run `gnome-panel`. There is absolutely no conflict with Unity, except of course, if you use a top panel from Gnome Panel, it will conflict with the upper panel from Unity. So delete the upper panel, or move it somewhere else. To make Gnome Panel start automatically at login, use the startup applications dialog in the system menu in the upper right corner.

Note: in Gnome Panel 3, you have to press the alt-key and right-click to get the menus to add/remove panels and applets. Alt+middleclick is used to move applets on the panel. Except for that, they're just the same as they've been in earlier versions. There are many other panels available as well, of course. For instance, here's my Unity desktop with a bottom xfce4-panel.

[image]